# Ignore TransactionScope for specific query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-5, transactionscope

I'm looking for a way to execute a query while a TransactionScope is alive, and ignore the TransactionScope - basically, I want to execute this particular query no matter what.

I'm using EF code-first, and the way the application is designed, a new data context is opened many times throughout a single call, each with its own changes, and all of those are contained within a single TransactionScope, which has `Complete()` called at the end assuming no failures. Inside of the context we've overridden `SaveChanges` so that if any exception happens on `base.SaveChanges()`, we can catch it and log to the database before rolling back the transaction.

Since the `SaveChanges` happens inside the transaction, the logging obviously doesn't happen, because it belongs to the same transaction as the original call. I'm trying to ignore the TransactionScope altogether just for the logging code.

Here's some stripped-down code:

```
// From the context
public override int SaveChanges() {
    try {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        // Writes to the log table - I want this to run no matter what
        LogRepo.Log(/*stuff to log from the context*/);

        throw;
    }
}

// Inside the business logic
public void DoSomething() {
    try {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) {

            using (var context = new FooContext()) {
                // Do something
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            using (var context = new FooContext()) {
                // Do something else
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            scope.Complete();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // scope.Complete is never called, so the transaction is rolled back
    }
}
```

I tried using regular ADO.NET instead of EF for the logging, but still the same results - it gets rolled back too.

I need the error handling to happen inside of `SaveChanges`, because what I'm logging is the state of the entities that are being saved - so I can't just easily move the logging somewhere else. I could build the message while inside the `SaveChanges catch`, and throw it and let `DoSomething catch` log it, but there are dozens of `DoSomething` methods, and I'd much rather just deal with this in one place.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you wrap your log call inside of another transaction scope with the suppress option enabled, transaction scope will not be used.

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
    try {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {
            LogRepo.Log(message); // stuff to log from the context
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Tested and it works in both regular ADO.NET and Entity Framework. Thanks.

Comment: Just implemented this and now i get this error: Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.  i read that opening multiple transactions can cause this error?

Comment: This just saved me a lot of headache! I'm processing MSMQ messages inside a transaction, but need to reach out to SQL Azure for a little extra data and they don't support DTC. Using this enabled my transactions to still work, while also letting Azure function.

Answer (score 1):

Just my initial thought, but you need to put your LogRepo on it's own DataContext (DC2) so that the surrounding TransactionScope (with DC1) won't roll it back when it's not committed.

Basically, you need to make your logging self-contained and atomic.

*EDIT* In looking at it some more, it seems to me that if you moved your Logging out from the SaveChanges into the catch() on DoSomething(), your logging would work. But, your logging still needs to be self-contained and atomic.

Comment: The TransactionScope wraps itself around every data context that's inside of it - the LogRepo does create its own brand new context, but it's still picked up by the TransactionScope.

Comment: For your edit - I mentioned that - I need to at least build the error message from inside `SaveChanges` because I need access to the open data context, but even if I build the message from there and throw it to the caller, I'd still have to execute the logging in the caller several dozens of times, and I'm trying to keep it all in one place.

Comment: Yeah, pretty clear that your implementation won't work as designed. The other option would be to take your LogRepo and make it a singleton, created on app startup, with it's own DBContext created outside of all transaction scopes. Not the cleanest design, but it would get you around this TransactionScope business. I haven't found a way to "unenlist" a context from a TransactionScope just yet...

Comment: Thanks - I don't think I'm comfortable with keeping an open context for the entire life of the application, but I'll consider it.

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution that I'm not really happy with, but seems to work. TransactionScope apparently only affects the current thread, so logging using a new thread seems to work ok.

```
public override int SaveChanges() {
    try {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        string message = /*stuff to log from the context*/;
        new Thread(msg => {    

            LogRepo.Log(msg);

        }).Start(message);

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: That definitely has an "icky" feeling to it, but if it works, it works. Kind of like the singleton suggestion I had. I don't like it either, but it would definitely have worked.

Comment: @JoeBrunscheon +1 for "icky" :)

Comment: It's ok when I debug. but in release mode or in run it is not working :(